# How to solve the proguard error code 1 with Admob

Tags: android, proguard

I hope to following google's new instruction about admob and update my program. If testing in device, it works ok. When I export to APK. The console has some warning and error code 1. I tried to change the proguard setting and can't solve. Who can give me idea?

Following is the proguard.cfg setting:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames 
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses    
-dontpreverify 
-verbose   
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity   
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application   
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service   
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver   
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider   
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper   
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference   
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService   
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {   
native <methods>;   
}   
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {   
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);   
}   
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {   
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);   
}   
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {   
public void *(android.view.View);   
}   
-keepclassmembers enum * {   
public static **[] values();   
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);   
}   
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {   
 public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;   
}   

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**     
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }   
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }   
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.**   
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment 

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
public *;
}
-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
public *;
}
```

And than, following is the Error message from console:

```
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] Warning:         com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find referenced method 'void     setShowsDialog(boolean)' in class com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.google.android.gms.common.api.d
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers.
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-10-10 10:49:58 - admobTestingApp] at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Thank you for your help!